# Can haproxy be configured to understand SSL sessions without being sticky to time

Tags: haproxy

Am using HAProxy version haproxy-1.4.24 on a SLES 11 SP3 server. I need to load balance (using least connections or round robin) between 3 servers which talk only SSL. A session from client to server starts with client/server handshake followed by a series of "chatty" messages and then close of session.

I do not want to use stick src directive since it needs a time limit argument, making my load balancing ineffective.

Below is the configuration file am using. Can someone let me know how to achieve per session stickiness (one client sticks to one server until the SSL session ends)?

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    #chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    #stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    #user haproxy
    #group haproxy
    daemon

defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000

frontend localnodes
    bind *:80
    bind *:443
    mode tcp
    default_backend nodes

backend nodes
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    stick-table type ip size 200k expire 30m
    stick on src
    server s1 s1.mydomain.com:443 check
    server s2 s2.mydomain.com:443 check
    server s3 s3.mydomain.com:443 check
```